# Unity Build wrong aspect ratio in full screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've made a new 2D Unity Project in v2020.3.25f1 and set Fullscreen Mode to "Maximized Window".
[image]
When I build the app the whole screen is filled:
[image]
But when I exit full screen, reopen the app and switch back to full screen I get this:
[image]
Is this a bug? Is it caused by MacOS? It's driving me insane. ;(

Answer (score 1):

Unity saves the last resolution you left the application at. If you left it at 800x600, next time you launch it it will be 800x600.

When you exit fullscreen, it makes the app another aspect ratio. When you re-launch it, it re-launches at the weird aspect ratio.

**Solution Idea 1**

You could enable resizable window, that will most likely be a quick solution.

**Solution Idea 2**

You could also force the game to be a certain resolution when the game starts.

```
Screen.SetResolution(WIDTH, HEIGHT, IS_FULLSCREEN);
```

So in your case, it would be (assuming your screen is 1080p)

```
Screen.SetResolution(1920, 1080, true);
```

Comment: Enabling resizable window doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I searched around a bit and there seems to be no easy way to fix this other than forcefully setting the resolution. Try my second solution idea. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Then I need to determine if it's in full screen & get my screen resolution. Why must this be so difficult? ;(

Comment: Alternatively, you could disallow fullscreen switching and add it manually. Checking the F11 key and forcing resolution maybe? When F11 is pressed, if not fullscreen make it fullscreen and set resolution to monitor resolution. I have the same issue in my game and this is the method I'm using.

Comment: Now I can't exit full screen:
if (Screen.fullScreen)
   Screen.SetResolution(Display.main.systemWidth, Display.main.systemHeight, true);

Comment: the true at the end is the fullscreen variable. if (Screen.fullScreen) Screen.SetResolution(..., ..., false); should get it to work.